# Appending to a list of list in python

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I'm trying to append an item to a list of list with a for loop but encountering an **IndexError: list index out of range** error.

```
class Solution:
    
    counter = [[]]
    
    def test(self):  
        i = 0
        while i < 5:
            Solution.counter[i].append(i)
            i += 1

        print(Solution.counter)

sol = Solution()
sol.test()
```

Comment: you dont have counter[1] . It shouldn't be counter[i] , just put counter[0].append(i)

Comment: It's a list of list and I want to append items in a different index each time.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as i = 1, Python trys to find the second value in the list, but its currently `[[0]]`. So there is no second list on which you can append 1. But you can do it like this:

```
class Solution:

counter = [] # <--- Note this 

def test(self):  
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        Solution.counter.append([i]) # <-- Appending list with i in it
        i += 1

    print(Solution.counter)
```

This should work (assuming you want `counter` to be `[[0], [1], [2], ...]`, if not I got you wrong).

Comment: I'm expecting the same expected output as you but I tried this and still get the same error.

Comment: sorry this works but is there any way I can choose which index I append.

Comment: For this purpose, you can take a look at `insert()`: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/insert

You can use it instead of `append()`.

Comment: Hi sorry for so many questions but I'm trying to append an item to an array of array with the given index. For example, if there exists a list of list  ```[[1],[2,4,6],[100,101,102]]``` and I want to append 8 to the 1st index so it would become ```[[1],[2,4,6,8],[100,101,102]] ```.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# I have checked it, its running

class Solution:
    
    counter = []
    
    def test(self):  
        i = 0
        while i < 5:
            Solution.counter.append(i)
            i += 1

        print(Solution.counter)

sol = Solution()
sol.test()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is meant to promote _learning_. For this reason, answers should not only include corrected or improved code, but also an explanation of _how_ and _why_ the implementation works. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful, and even if the code “should be self explanatory” adding explanation ensures _everyone_ can understand. Please edit your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).